# Can't vote to close as dupe on ios Safari

Tags: support, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, iphone, ipad

Tried to close a PHP question as a dupe, but after pasting the link <strike>or typing</strike> in the input box, the confirm button just stays disabled and the preview never appears. Took me ages to find the dupe link too. Onscreen keyboards are not good for productivity!

Answer (score 1):

I sure can vote to close on iPhone 4 so I'm not sure exactly what you're talking about here.

Are you maybe unaware of the two finger scroll?

Comment: I made a mistake, this only happens when you copy/paste the link into the box.  You also have to select all to delete the default text.  Typing *after* pasting doesn't work either. iPhone 4.  I tried the two finger scroll and also the five finger death punch with no luck.